# Detect key input in Python

Tags: python, input, tkinter, keyboard

*(In 2013)* I don't know why Python is that weird, you can't find this by searching in google very easily, but it's quite simple.

How can I detect 'SPACE' or actually any key?
How can I do this:

```
print('You pressed %s' % key)
```

This should be included in python core, so please do not link modules not related for core python.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could make a little Tkinter app:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def onKeyPress(event):
    text.insert('end', 'You pressed %s\n' % (event.char, ))

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
text = tk.Text(root, background='black', foreground='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', 12))
text.pack()
root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: does using Tk require a graphical window?  I'm working on an embedded system.  the sys.strin.read() below is tempting, but you need to press enter.

Comment: @user391339: I think Tk would require a window system, or a virtual display. For an embedded system, a `getch` recipe such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21659588/190597) might be better.

Answer (score 3):

Use Tkinter
there are a ton of tutorials online for this.
basically, you can create events. Here is a [link](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) to a great site!
This makes it easy to capture clicks.
Also, if you are trying to make a game, Tkinter also has a GUI.
Although, I wouldn't recommend Python for games at all, it could be a fun experiment.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Key input is a predefined event. You can catch events by attaching `event_sequence`(s) to `event_handle`(s) by using one or multiple of the existing binding methods(`bind`, `bind_class`, `tag_bind`, `bind_all`). In order to do that:

1. define an `event_handle` method
2. pick an event(`event_sequence`) that fits your case from [an events list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32289175/7032856)

When an event happens, all of those binding methods implicitly calls the `event_handle` method while passing an `Event` object, which includes information about specifics of the event that happened, as the argument.

In order to detect the key input, one could first catch all the `'<KeyPress>'` or `'<KeyRelease>'` events and then find out the particular key used by making use of `event.keysym` attribute.

Below is an example using `bind` to catch both `'<KeyPress>'` and `'<KeyRelease>'` events on a particular widget(`root`):

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def event_handle(event):
    # Replace the window's title with event.type: input key
    root.title("{}: {}".format(str(event.type), event.keysym))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    event_sequence = '<KeyPress>'
    root.bind(event_sequence, event_handle)
    root.bind('<KeyRelease>', event_handle)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

use the builtin: (no need for tkinter)

```
s = input('->>')
print(s) # what you just typed); now use if's 
if s == ' ':
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pynput
[tutorial here for taking hint](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-pynput-to-make-a-keylogger/)

Its very **difficult** to do without a module.
But *pynput* is a core package.