# Detecting input keys (Python 3.4.2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

This is probably pretty simple, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I basically want some code that detects different key presses (enter, left etc) and then saves the type of key in a variable.

Comment: What OS are you using? Does it need to detect all key presses everywhere, or just ones that occur when your application has keyboard focus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect key input in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815686/detect-key-input-in-python)

Comment: I am using Windows 8, and just ones that occur when my program asks for a key press (result must differ depending on key). I don't want a new pop-up window, just keep it in the command prompt.

Comment: There are a few libraries that support keyboard input like Tkinter and PyGame. Have you checked them out? Might add a little too much functionality than you probably want though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows and only want to get input when your window has keyboard focus, you can use [`msvcrt.getch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch):

> Read a keypress and return the resulting character. Nothing is echoed to the console.

Comment: How would I make the console wait for a key press (input doesn't work)?

Comment: `getch` waits for a keypress.

Comment: When I run the code it just prints `b'\xff'` without waiting for me to press something.

Comment: Strange, works on my machine... Maybe that's behavior specific to Windows 8. I'm still on 7.

Comment: Found the reason, I was using IDLE instead of the command prompt. Thanks anyway