# What is the equivalent for onkeydown and onkeyup (Javascript events) in python?

Tags: javascript, python, dom-events, keyboard-events, onkeydown

There are events called 'onkeydown' and 'onkeyup' in Javascript. Can anyone please suggest the python equivalent of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect key input in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815686/detect-key-input-in-python)

Comment: The javascript events you are referring to are specific to web-browsers. In what context would your python code be running?

Answer (score 1):

Without any external library, python can't provide GUI features, such as events handling. Listening to an event such `onkeydown` or `onkeyup` is thus impossible with the python sdl.

If you really want to react to these events, you must use an external library providing event-driven operations, such as the [Qt](http://www.qt.io/developers/) binding [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), the [TKinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) module, or other libraries.

Comment: Detecting keystrokes isn't something specific to GUIs — which the OP never mentioned — and is quite possible without one.

Comment: @martineau So answer to the OP's question!

Comment: There's no single way to do it as it's an OS dependent operation.

Comment: @martineau So this discussion is just useless

Comment: No, I don't think it's useless. My point was that your statement that it's impossible in Python without a GUI library/module is incorrect.

Comment: @martineau actually `spirine` is right, there is no easy way to track `key_up` and `key_down` events, you could catch only key_press. Feel the difference. And using key_press and key repeat action you could do the workaround. However there is a another thing like pygame.

Comment: @martineau But is it constructive for the OP? Couldn't you help hime, instead of trying to show me in what extend I'm wrong?

Comment: The context of the question was an equivalent to some event handlers *of a web browser window*. It is indeed impossible to have a window and the equivalent event handlers without, well, a GUI. If the context is instead a console application, then it's just text input, and the question is not too well phrased.