# Event driven programming without gui

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, eventhandler

I'm looking for a python module to which allows me to handle events. These events may be triggered by

- timers
- i2c input (e.g. buttons)

I'm building a [wordclock](http://www.timeanddate.com/wordclock/) (with the bibliopixel module) and would like to display the time in a main loop.
On the RPI, I've got a temperature and humidity sensor installed. So, I need to suspend the main loop and scroll text (or display any other animation). This could be triggered by a timer or i2c input. After that I'd like to jump back to the loop.

*What is the 'standard' module for such tasks? There are tons of modules, but finding the best one is difficult for me as I'm not precisely sure, what features I need...*

Regards,
Achim

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966204/what-is-the-equivalent-for-onkeydown-and-onkeyup-javascript-events-in-python/29966394#29966394)'s a similar question. But I'm afraid it was left unanswered.

Comment: Don't build a clock. They might mistaken it with a bomb.