# Passing on an object from one class to another class that is called with it's main() function

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

My program starts with a '`Loading_UI`' class that shows a simple loading bar and creates an object that contains data fetched from .csv files.

When the loading (= data fetching) is completed, the loading bar destroys itself (`root.destroy()`) and then I want to pass on the object that I created to another class that will show the main UI of the program. To keep things neat, I want to call the main UI from its own .py file and own `Main_UI` class.

Using the idea above, my question is: how can I pass the object on from the `Loading_UI` class to the `Main_UI` class?

(Run the program from `RUN_loading.py`)

*(`DataBase.py`)  Simple object creation:*

```
class DataBase:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def show_content(self):
        print(self.name)
```

And in the other .py file with class `Loading_UI`, something like this:

*(`RUN_Loading.py`)  UI with loading bar simulation:*

```
from tkinter import *
from DataBase import DataBase

class Loading_UI:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.DataBase = DataBase("This is our object.")
        self.load_pct = DoubleVar()
        self.load_pct.set(0)
        loading_bar = Label(textvariable = self.load_pct)
        loading_bar.grid()

        self.handle_loading_progress()

    def handle_loading_progress(self):

        if self.load_pct.get() < 10:
            self.load_pct.set(self.load_pct.get() + 1)
            self.master.after(200, self.handle_loading_progress)
        else:
            self.show_main()

    def show_main(self):

        root.destroy()
        from UI_Main import Main_UI
        Main = Main_UI(self.DataBase)
        Main.main()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100+300+300")
app = Loading_UI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And the main UI which would need to process the object would look like this.

*(UI_Main.py)  Main UI Window that pops up after loading is complete.*

```
from tkinter import *

class Main_UI:

    def __init__(self, database_object):

        self.DataBase = database_object

        # Run this function to check that the 
        # data object is properly received.
        self.DataBase.show_content()

root = Tk()
app = Main_UI(root, database_object)
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above is obviously wrong, but I just want to present the idea what I am after.  Running the code above gives:

> NameError: name 'database_object' is not defined

EDIT: Edited the code with a practical (simplified) example.

Comment: There should probably be a single class that starts both the `Loading_UI` and the `Main_UI` that would facilitate passing an object from one to the other.

Comment: Can't the same be done across different .py files, each with their own class? It's easier to maintain and gives much shorter code.

Comment: So where does `database_object` *get* defined? It would be easier to answer with a more complete version of `Loading_UI` and how it gets used

Comment: The database class is imported to 'Loading_UI' and then instantiated there.  It's an object that contains information from the csv files.  The actual code is not relevant here, since I only want to pass the object on to the main class.  It may as well be e.g. a variable that is passed on.

Comment: And that is trivial; you save the return value of what ever method returns the object, and pass that to `Main_UI`. Without seeing what `Loading_UI` looks like, though, we can't be any more specific.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provided a [mcve]

Comment: I slimmed down the code in all 3 files with an easy, practical example. I hope this will help to get it solved!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this might be to create a Main_UI object in Loading_UI file.

Loading_UI.py:

```
import Main_UI

# Create your progress bar
data = getDataFromCSV('file.csv')
# Delete your progress bar

main_ui = Main_Ui(data)
```

Comment: I may be missing the point here, but that seems similar to what I am doing above. I just need to be able to draw a new UI window as well.

Comment: Why does the main window have to be created from Main_UI ? Can't you put your main window creation in the Loading_UI.py file ?

Comment: I'm trying to minimalise the code to make it easier to read and modify.

Comment: I think this is the best approach. Just import your GUI load object, then when it's done simply destroy it. I don't think there will be an approach more readable & maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in tkinter but I've researched its documentation a little bit and this is how I'd do it.

Tkinter(as pygtk for that matter) has the concept of events and signals that are fired upon them. You can [bind](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php) an event in any tkinter widget (such as a progressbar)  using the `bind` function and have a callback function that will act on this. Apparently there's a predefined list of tkinter [events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289175/list-of-all-tkinter-events) that are available and in your case I think the `<Destroy> A widget is being destroyed.` will be of use.

So in your `loading_ui.py` file:

```
widget = ttk.Progressbar(parent, option=value, ...) # create your progressbar

#Bind it to the destroy event. Once destroyed call the proceed_with_main function and pass your object
widget.bind('<Destroy> ', lambda event, db=self.DataBase:
                         self.proceed_with_main(db)) 

def proceed_with_main(db): 
    from UI_Main import Main_UI

    Main = Main_UI(db)
    Main.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok multiple things are not done right here. Corrections are posted in the code directly.

(Run_loading.py)

```
from tkinter import *
from DataBase import DataBase

class Loading_UI:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.DataBase = DataBase("This is our object.")
        self.load_pct = DoubleVar()
        self.load_pct.set(0)
        loading_bar = Label(textvariable = self.load_pct)
        loading_bar.grid()

        self.handle_loading_progress()

    def handle_loading_progress(self):

        if self.load_pct.get() < 10:
            self.load_pct.set(self.load_pct.get() + 1)
            self.master.after(200, self.handle_loading_progress)
        else:
            self.show_main()

    def show_main(self):

        root.destroy()
        from UI_Main import Main_UI
        Main = Main_UI(self.DataBase)
        # Main.main() This line is wrong, your object Main_UI() does not have a defined 'main()' function

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100+300+300")
app = Loading_UI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

(UI_Main.py)

```
from tkinter import *

class Main_UI:

    def __init__(self, database_object):

        self.DataBase = database_object

        # Run this function to check that the 
        # data object is properly received.
        self.DataBase.show_content()
        self.tkWindow = Tk() # if you want to keep an new window you could keep this
        self.tkWindow.mainloop()

""" You shouldn't do things outside of the __init__() function of this class.
root = Tk()  lines to delete
app = Main_UI(root, database_object) lines to delete
root.mainloop() lines to delete """

""" This part is not necessary 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main() """
```