# Disable button if entry is edited in tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, tkinter-entry

this is pretty much my code, the submit button is disabled until the string button is used. What I'd like to do is to have the disabled again if there is any edit to the name and surname entry or maybe, if it is simpler, just if they are clicked. How could I achieve this? thank you

````
        surname = Label(self, text="surname:", font=('arial', 12)).place(relx=0.07, rely=0.093, height=15, width=100)
        def edit_name(event):
            self.name.config(state='disable')     

        self.name = StringVar(self)
        self.name.set('')
        self.name=Entry(self,textvariable = self.name, width=280, bg='WHITE')
        self.name.place(relx=0.19, rely=0.05, height=25, width=160)
        self.name.bind("<KeyRelease>", edit_name)

        self.surnname = StringVar(self)
        self.surname.set('')
        self.surname=Entry(self,textvariable = self.surname, width=280, bg='WHITE')
        self.surname.place(relx=0.19, rely=0.090, height=25, width=160)

        ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind callbacks to any event on name and surname Entry widget eg:

`self.surname.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.__onSurnameEdited)`

Then in the callback you can modify the visibility of the button

For a list of events see here:
[List of All Tkinter Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289175/list-of-all-tkinter-events)

Comment: Where exactly should I put that line code? I edited my code with what I'm doing and it disable the entry as soon the name is edited.

Comment: Isn't it submit button that you want to disable?