# Prevent arrow keys input numbers in Python (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, numbers, key

I use the keyboard library and after giving  `on_press_key`  to my numpad, the arrow keys give the following values:

left - 4
Up - 8
Right - 6
Down - 2

How can I prevent this?

It looks like the arrow keys share the same event as those corresponding numeric keys

Comment: Why are you using a keyboard library? Shouldn't you use tkinter bindings?

Comment: Just took a look around Tkinter bindings, but there isn't any detailed documentation

Comment: Use `<any tkinter widget/window>.bind(<sequence>, <function>)` where the sequence can be any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289245/11106801). If you have any specific questions on tkinter, ask me :D

Comment: Played with it yesterday and I figured it out. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad that I can help :D