# Tkinter widgets only drawn if I press alt button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a small app on Linux in which I sub-class the Frame class from **tkinter** and sometime the widgets are only drawn after I press the `alt` button. Everything works fine, though this is the first time I use this GUI and I may miss something.

Follows a short example of my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyFrame(Frame):   
    def one_method(self):
        root_frame.geometry("200x400")
        button = Button(self, command=self.clean_and_draw_more_widget, text="Hello")
        button.pack(side=TOP) #I also use grid()
```

the main driver code:

```
root_frame = Tk()
root_frame.title("Window")  
 
frame = MyFrame(root_frame)
frame.pack()

root_frame.mainloop()
```

As you can see nothing compless, but still I have this problem.

**EDIT**
I use grid() and pack() but each one in different methods

Thanks for helping

Comment: "click the alt button" - Do you mean "press the Alt key on my keyboard ?

Comment: "pack(side=TOP) #I also use grid()" - Never do that. Choose one of them, and stick with it.

Comment: Have you looked at how `tkinter` bindings work?

Comment: @Programmer I disagree. I think OP is saying that they might use either `.pack` or `.grid`. You don't have to pick one and stick with it for the whole project. You can have different geometry managers in each `tkinter.Tk`/`tkinter.Frame`/`tkinter.Toplevel`.

Comment: And please create a [Minimal Reproducible ___Runnable___ Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TheLizzard no, you don't have to stick to one for the whole project, but you can't use `pack` and `grid` on the same widget. The OP should reformulate that code comment to make clear whether he uses both methods in his project or on the same widget.

Comment: @Programmer I think OP already knows that and I can't see any evidence of OP using both `.pack` and `.grid` in their `MyFrame` class. It looks like OP will either `.pack` or `.grid` in that frame but for simplification purposes OP chose `.pack`.

Comment: @TheLizzard I cannot use it :(

Comment: @AntonioMolinaro Use `<any tkinter widget/window>.bind(<sequence>, <function>)`, where `<sequence>` can be any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289175/list-of-all-tkinter-events)

Comment: @TheLizard I dont use bind() because as I said above I can't use it

Comment: @AntonioMolinaro That is why I am trying to explain it. Using `tkinter` without `.bind` can be very very difficult. If you want to know how it works look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/193357) as well

Comment: @TheLizzard You saying that each command must be bind to the root Frame ?

Comment: @AntonioMolinaro You can to any function to any tkinter widget. Also the code that you have given works fine. What do you mean by *"the widgets are only drawn after I press the `alt` button."*? Do they just not appear on your screen? What Python/Tcl versions do you have?

Comment: @TheLizzard Yes the frame is completely empty(gray) and the version is 8.6

Comment: @AntonioMolinaro What OS are you using? If you are using python 3.x on Windows 10 try reinstalling python.

Comment: @TheLizzard I use Ubuntu linux and python3