# How to bind key "<" in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, keyevent

My code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

def Hello():
    print("You press '<' key")

root.bind("<", Hello)
root.mainloop()
```

But I receive error:

> _tkinter.TclError: no event type or button # or keysym

I tried `"<<>"` and `"Shift-,"` but it does not work.

Comment: is "less than" `<less>` what you're looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of All Tkinter Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289175/list-of-all-tkinter-events)

Comment: Probably you could clarify in words or images which key you want to bind (e.g. _less-than_ which is same as _open angle-bracket_ as opposed to _left-arrow_). Different interpretations already lead to discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is this:

```
root.bind("<less>", Hello)
```

You can find a compete list of Key-Synonyms in the [original documentation of Tk](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.html).