# Is there a click event handler in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, events, click, mouse

Guys I'm writing a GUI in tkinter. I wanted to handle click events like whenever a user use the 'left' mouse button on the GUI. This is for playing a sound when a user clicks. So is there any functions like:

```py
onClick(lambda: play()) #call a function
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, you should check `bind` ~ `root.bind_all('<Button-1>',func)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of All Tkinter Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289175/list-of-all-tkinter-events)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a click event to a canvas.

Something like this should work:

```py
root = Tk()

def on_click(event):
    print("you clicked")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
canvas.pack()

# Canvas.focus_set is required if the window already contains a widget that has keyboard/input focus
canvas.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

Here are some examples of using this method: https://python-course.eu/tkinter/events-and-binds-in-tkinter.php